# Updating multiple lines from table using an UPDATE line with select

Tags: sql, select, multiple-columns

I have this problem

I would like to update a table using the following SQL sentence.

```
update materia_prima
set cantidad = cantidad - ((select cantidad from detalle_producto
                            where codigo_producto=1) * 15)
```

15 is a quantity that I will set with a variable with PHP, it may change.

This is the primary sentence:(which is used in PHP)

```
update materia_prima set cantidad=cantidad - ((select cantidad from detalle_producto where codigo_producto=\"$this->codigo_producto\") * \"$this->cantidad\"
```

materia_prima is a inventory table of raw materials

detalle_product is a table that has default quantities with raw materials quantities that are needed to create an specific product

My problem is that using that sentence SQL, it says that it is a multiple select, and I need to update my inventory

Please help

Comment: Which error are you getting? Are you getting multiple rows in the subquery?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: When I run my SQL sentence, it shows me this error.

Error
consulta SQL: Documentación


update materia_prima set cantidad=cantidad - ((select cantidad from detalle_producto where codigo_producto=1) * 15)
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1242 - Subconsulta retorna mas que 1 línea

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it

This  answer  is for PHP

```
public function DecreaseRW() {
        $sql = "UPDATE materia_prima mp INNER JOIN detalle_producto dp ON mp.id = dp.codigo_materia_prima  SET mp.cantidad = mp.cantidad - ( dp.cantidad * \"$this->cantidad\" )WHERE dp.codigo_producto = \"$this->codigo_producto\"";
        Executor::doit($sql);
    }
```